# How I can send entire ETH balance from one account to another with web3.py? <SOLVED>

Tags: web3js, python

sorry for being noob but I need little help.
I'm trying to use web3 to transfer all of the balance of an account to another account.
I read here on other topics that I need to subtract the Total Balance by gas*price, and that would be my amount to send.

> Amount_to_send = totalBalance - (gas*price)

But how i can implement it in the code?
Here is mine:

```
from web3 import Web3

url = "http://********************"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))

account_1 = "0xD4D*************************************"
account_2 = "0x4AD*************************************"

private_key = "**********************************************************"                                                                                    

nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_1)

tx = {
    "nonce": nonce,     
    "to": account_2,
    "value": web3.toWei(1, "ether"),    
    "gas": 2000000,
    "gasPrice": web3.toWei("50", "gwei")
}

signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)

tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

EDIT: here is the solution in case somebody need it: I just made two variables "val" and "total_gas" outside "tx", and then use it to get a value.

```
        val = web3.eth.getBalance("sender address")
        total_gas = web3.toWei("50", "gwei") * 21000

        tx = {
            "nonce": nonce,
            "to": receive_account,
            "gas": 21000,
            "gasPrice": web3.toWei("50", "gwei"),
            "value": val - total_gas
        }
```

Comment: Use the formula Amount_to_send = totalBalance - (gas*price) for the value parameter of the tx